# Autowiring Map not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, ioc-container

I'm using Spring 3.0.4. I have some beans that use the @Autowired annotation on Maps. These maps are defined within an application-context.xml file (as these maps are constructed using several factory methods).

When I use my debugger, I can see the map gets constructed using the properly (expected) bean id. However, once the autowiring process starts, it claims it cannot find a bean with the id that just has been created.

Piece of code:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("dienstverbandMap")
private Map<String, String> dienstverbandMap;
```

Piece of context xml:

```
<bean class="java.util.HashMap" id="dienstverbandMap" factory-bean="someFactoryMethod" factory-method="getMappedMap"/>
```

Important detail, when I change the type to java.lang.Object in both my Class and the context xml it *does get wired* In fact, I can cast it to a HashMap in my code and get everything to work. But that is not what i want obviously.

Anyone got an explantion what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is something to do with the type parameters for `dienstverbandMap`.  The injection can only be performed safely if Spring can figure out that the bean instance (a `HashMap`) was actually instantiated as a `HashMap<String, String>`.  Spring could be losing the type parameters because of the bean's declared type is a raw type.

Another possibility is that the result signature of the factory method is wrong; e.g. Map instead of HashMap, or a raw HashMap rather than a `HashMap<String, String>`.

(Some of these theories could be disproved if you showed us the declaration of the factory method.)

---

By the way, according to the comments in the spring-beans 2.0 DTD and 3.0 XSD, the `class` attribute is not used if you supply a `factory-bean` attribute.  Have you tried leaving it out entirely?

Comment: You're right. My factory method signature returns Map<>, when I changed that to HashMap, everything began to work. Thanks!! :)

Comment: I figured, the factory implemented an Interface which forced the return type to be a Map (or more specific). However, even then it did not work. I had to change the interface in order to get this to work. Yuk :)

Answer (score 5):

[3.11.3. Fine-tuning annotation-based autowiring with qualifiers:](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation-qualifiers)

Quote:
If you intend to express annotation-driven injection by name, do not primarily use @Autowired - even if is technically capable of referring to a bean name through @Qualifier values. Instead, prefer the JSR-250 @Resource annotation which is semantically defined to identify a specific target component by its unique name, with the declared type being irrelevant for the matching process.

As a specific consequence of this semantic difference, beans which are themselves defined as a collection or map type cannot be injected via @Autowired since type matching is not properly applicable to them. Use @Resource for such beans, referring to the specific collection/map bean by unique name.

Comment: Is there any more documentation you recommend regarding the @Resource annotation?

Comment: Just a note, when I tried the Resource annotation, it worked fine in Tomcat, but it did not work in JBoss. It looks like the @Resource annotation handler is platform dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure your factory method returns `java.util.Map`, not `java.util.HashMap`, so I guess you could probably do this:

```
<bean class="java.util.Map" id="dienstverbandMap"
      factory-bean="someFactoryMethod" factory-method="getMappedMap"/>
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sure if Spring will let you do that as `Map` is an interface, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've tried setting the bean type to java.util.Map . But to no avail. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

The bean definition for the map does not contain the type parameters, so auto-wiring cannot confirm that it is of the correct type.

If you use `<util:map>` you can specify the type parameters, but then obviously can't use your own factory method. The only other solutions are to make your bean require a raw `Map` (bad) or explicitly wire the maps in the bean definition (better).